# How to create a SQL Query to get all items with higher value comparing two columns

Tags: mysql, sql

I had this table in my mysql schema:

```
   id    | user_id    | cellphone_id    |    favorited_at        | unfavorited_at
    1    |   234      |     7           |   2019-04-09 12:35:02  |    
    2    |   234      |     5           |   2019-04-09 13:00:02  |
    4    |   234      |     7           |   2019-04-09 12:35:02  | 2019-04-10 12:35:02
```

This table represent a history from all cellphone favorite by an application user.

in the example above the cellphone_id 7 was favorite at 2019-04-09 and after was unfavorite at 2019-04-10.

So I would like to build a query to select all cellphone favorite by user at this moment, so when I run the query the result should be something like this:

```
 SELECT * FROM favorite_user_cellphone
 WHERE user_id = 234 AND <something.....>
```

the result should be:

```
   id    | user_id    | cellphone_id    |    favorited_at        | unfavorited_at  
    2    |   234      |     5           |   2019-04-09 13:00:02  |
```

Should be return only cellphone_id 5 because the cellphone_id 7 was favorited and after unfavorited.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `NOT EXISTS` query:

```
SELECT *
FROM t
WHERE unfavorited_at IS NULL
AND NOT EXISTS (
    -- t is a favorited record
    -- x is an unfavorited record that is more recent than t
    SELECT 1
    FROM t AS x
    WHERE user_id        = t.user_id
    AND   cellphone_id   = t.cellphone_id
    AND   unfavorited_at > t.favorited_at
)
```

Comment: But I need keep the history of the when user favorite and unfavorite the cellphone.

Comment: @andre row #4 contains both dates... you could actually fill both columns in row #1 and not create row #4

Comment: yes, I understand, but suppose that the application user did favorite the device again? I will lose the history of the first date that he favorite.

Answer (score 0):

For a single user, I think you can use `order by` and `limit`:

```
SELECT uc.*
FROM favorite_user_cellphone uc
WHERE user_id = 234 AND <something.....>
ORDER BY favorited_at DESC
LIMIT 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Select * from 
favorite_user_cellphone uc
where user_id = 234 and favorited_at is not null And cellphone_id  not in 
(
Select cellphone_id  from 
favorite_user_cellphone uc
where user_id = 234 and unfavorited_at is not null)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use it

SELECT * FROM favorite_user_cellphone WHERE user_id = 234 AND NOT IN (SELECT cellphone_id FROM favorite_user_cellphone WHERE user_id = 234 and  unfavorited_at is Not Null)